# Split testing sending emails: time of day & day of week

Tags: statistical-significance, marketing

My name is Lauren Nickoloff and I work in the marketing department of a small business coaching company.

I'm preparing a split test for the purpose of determining which days of the week and which times of day are when our audience opens our emails the most.

And I am getting stuck on how to design the test for optimal validity & significance.

My question is: How to I design the experiment so that I can get an answer that is conclusive?

Ideas I have on how to design the test are: 
1. Test each paired combination (ex. Monday VS tues, Mon vs wed, Mon vs, thurs, Mon vs Fri, Mon vs Sat, Mon vs Sun, Tues vs Wed, Tues VS, Thurs....etc.)
2. Use Bracket Scoring (ex. test Monday VS Tues AND Wed VS Thurs...then winners of first round compete against each other)
3. Choose a few variables based on the hypothesis (Hand pick 10-20 specific Days of week and time of day and only test those).

Which of the three options above (or a new, better option) do you recommend? Time to test and effort to test are of little importance compared to the importance of getting results that are statistically significant and valid.

Thanks!